# How to automate Wireshark GUI like IO Graph

Tags: wireshark, automation

I use a lot IO Graph in Wireshark but for each capture, I have to set again (and again...) all my "preferences" for X/Y Axis and Graph 2/3 filters and so on...

That is really annoying. I looked at Wireshark Lua reference API but found no way to trigger "IO Graph" window opening with my preferred options.

Is there a way to set default values for IO Graph options ?

What would you recommend me to use to automate this user-interaction task in Wireshark ?

Comment: Windows, linux or??

Comment: At the moment I analyze traffic on a Windows system but my favorite is Linux... So a solution for either of it (or both) suits me !

Comment: I think this is probably more for StackOverflow? Check out http://www.sikuli.org/ for automating GUI applications.

Comment: Do you need to see the I/O per host in wireshark or can you use an application like ntop to look at utilization?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

What might be useful here would be an option similar to what Quicken has for reports.

[Quicken](http://quicken.intuit.com) will, for at least some reports, show them with default options; however, if you've changed the options from the default, you can save the report, with a name, with the new options.  That doesn't save the report *data*, it just saves the *options*, so if you open up the report with that name, it recalculates the data based on the current state of your Quicken database.

The equivalent for Wireshark would be an option to save an I/O Graph's options with a name; you could then open up the named graph, and it would re-calculate the graph values based on the current capture and display that.

Please file an enhancement request for this at [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org), so that it can be tracked, and you can get notified if and when that feature gets added.

Comment: Good idea. In fact I think it will be even more flexible to be able to "drive" the full Wireshark GUI from Lua (but as far as I see, bindings lack)... so that any case, any needs may be fulfilled that way.

Comment: Being able to drive the GUI from Lua would be useful, but it'd also be useful to be able to remember a given I/O graph *without* having to write any code, in Lua or any other language.

Comment: I will have to list all configurable dialogs in Wireshark to avoid to create a bugzilla just for IO Graph. If you known already some of these dialogs that may benefits from a "preferences" or "templating" system, just list them here. Thanks